# LCD Identification FPC-JG00467-01B SR36

Tags: lcd, display

I salvaged an old LCD from a calculator (Texas Instruments) and I want to interface it with a microcontroller (preferably an Arduino). I‘ve searched the whole internet but I simply can‘t find any information about this display and its driver. I am looking for a specialist who can identify this:

[image: First Picture]

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a custom part for which there is no public data sheet. LCDs are almost always custom-designed, and require special driver circuitry. This is especially true for such mass-produced items as calculators.

**Edit:**

There is code to screen capture using an ESP32.

https://github.com/marcrobm/TTRX_Remote/blob/master/main/drivers/TTRX_T30X.cpp

The Protocol is a relatively simple parallel interface with some data pins and a clock pin. To implement a Driver, one could implement the above linked code "in reverse".